# My attempt to gather mathematical spaces in a drawing

Tags: soft-question, advice

There are many spaces (Sobolev, inner product spaces, etc.) that I am not using on a daily basis, but have to recall their definition from time to time. So I decided to draw a synthetic scheme of the most common ones.

Please don't pay too much attention to the colors and design, this is a draft.

Do you agree with the scheme?
Do you have any suggestions ("common" space missing)?

[image: scheme I'm writing about]

Comment: Some random suggestions: $L^p$-spaces, $C^k$-spaces, groups, Lie-groups, topological groups, measure spaces, probability spaces, completeness of metric spaces, (Banach) algebras. But do not feel forced to include those simply because I am writing them here!

Comment: @PhoemueX: TY, I'll think about it - more precisely, about where they should be added! (I'm not too sure for Lie-groups, e.g.) Do you see any mistakes on the drawing above?